# Hash function notations and their corresponding existing cryptographic hash algorithm

Tags: hash, sha-256, group-theory, access-control

I am implementing Role-based access control by referencing the paper [Enforcing Role-Based Access Control for Secure Data Storage in the Cloud](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/09/02/comjnl.bxr080.short). In page 6, they have mentioned to choose hash functions $H_1$ and $H_2$ during the setup
$$ H_1 : \{0, 1\}^∗ → Z^∗_p, H_2 : G_T →Z^∗_p $$
where $G_T$ be a cyclic multiplicative group

Can anyone please explain me the notation of the two hash functions?
Should the two hash functions $H_1$ and $H_2$ be implemented using different cryptographic hash algorithms? Or can I use SHA-256 (for example) to implement both of them? If No, please recommend me cryptographic hash algorithms for them.

Comment: does [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37305/23623) help you?